# Why does list coloring provides a more general setting to discuss the chromatic number?

Tags: graph-theory

I'm reading the *Handbook of Graph Theory*. It says the following:

> [image]

And a little before, the definitions of Chromatic Number:

> [image]

I don't understand what is this generality. Why the list permits more generality? To me, they seem the same idea: The idea of taking $k$ colors is similar to the idea of putting these colors in a list (at least I always thought of a list of these colors). So what's the difference in this case?

Answer (score 2):

In list coloring, different vertices can have different lists, while if you're just $k$-coloring a graph, then every vertex has the same $k$ colors available. There are bipartite ($2$-colorable) graphs with arbitrarily high choice number.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that when you talk about ordinary vertex colorings, each vertex has the same allowed list of colors: all of the colors that are available. A list assignment can assign a different set of allowed colors to each vertex; there’s a specific example in [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_coloring) showing a list assignment to the vertices of $K_{3,27}$ in which each vertex has only $3$ allowable colors. If every vertex gets the same set of allowable colors, you’re looking at the simple case of vertex coloring.

Comment: But are they always isomorphic one to each other?

Comment: @Vÿska: Are what always isomorphic to each other?

Comment: The list colorings.

Comment: @Vÿska: That question really doesn’t make much sense as it stands. What list colorings? Given a graph, you can make many different list assignments to its vertices, and for each of them you can in general produce many list colorings.